# Opera 11 (on Linux with KDE):  "Open in new tab" from Context Menu doesn't work

Tags: linux, kde, opera, opera-11

After updating to Opera 11, I find that I can't open a link in a new tab using the context menu.

I point my mouse on the desired link, press the right mouse button, and select from the context menu "Open in new tab" or "Open in new window" but nothing happens.

What is wrong?  Which settings should I check?

UPD: there are 5 "Open ..." variants in the context menu and no one works.

UPD2: My keyboard scheme is changed, but even after switching to default, menu doesnt work.

Comment: Are you using Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, or some other operating system?

Comment: Linux Os is used.

Comment: Which GUI are you using?  I wonder if there might be a known issue with a particular GUI.  Also, you should report this to Opera (I find they have been adding my feature suggestions that I submit through here too):  Help menu -> Report a site problem

Comment: I use KDE, but I can't say what gui framework is used by Opera (I downloaded `tar.gz`, and it does not link to any framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have another dialogue open for a different tab, such as the prompt to bookmark a page, which will prevent other GUI options from functioning correctly.  The easy way to clear up this particular problem is to just exit Opera, then come back (it will restore all your tabs, and Back/Forward history so you won't lose your position in your current workflow).

Alternatively, to open a link in a new tab, hold the Shift key (either one) while clicking once (with the left mouse button [since you seem to be using the default "right-handed mouse mode"]).

I use this feature frequently, and I find that holding down the Shift key to start a link in a new tab is a wonderful convenience.

Comment: restarting opera didn't help. Yes, Shift works (I use CTRL for this with other browser); but I also want sometimes to use context menu; without touching a keyboard.

Comment: If you're using the keyboard, you can also hold down the Shift key while pressing Enter to follow the selected link (using CTRL-Down/CTRL-Up) into a new tab.  I'm sorry, I'm not sure what's happened to your context menu, and am only trying to help you get working temporarily with alternatives until your context menu starts working again.

Comment: Randolf, can I change this key from Shift and Ctrl-Shift (background tab) to Ctrl+Shift and Ctrl?

Comment: For those who are interested, a complete list of all keyboard functions in Opera can be found here (for anyone who's new to Opera, this is a "must read" even if you mostly use the mouse):  http://help.opera.com/Windows/11.10/en/keyboard.html

Comment: @osgx:  When modifying the keystrokes (see my next comment), I VERY STRONGLY RECOMMEND that you first use the "Duplicate" option to create your own "customized keyboard set" instead of modifying the default one directly.  This way, you have a "manufacturer default" to fall back on in case you ever need it.

Comment: @osgx:  You can customize the keystrokes here:  CTRL-F12 (which will take you to the Preferences section) -> Advanced tab -> Shortcuts -> Keyboard Setup section

Comment: Randolf, thanks, I know where keyboard setup is; but I don't know where Shift+Click and Shift+Enter are.

Comment: @osgx:  That would be in the "Browser Window" category (look for "Enter" and "Shift Enter") since that's where you're using those keys.